# Converting to XOR conjunctive form

Tags: logic, theory, graph-theory, computation-theory, language-theory

The XOR conjunctive form is defined as follows : (a XOR b) and (c XOR d)...etc

and the SAT-XCF is the language defined by the precedent (XOR conjunctive) expressions that are satisfiable.

I would like to know the SAT-XCF is NP hard ? Thus, is there a function able to convert any satisfiable boolean expression into a satisfiable XOR conjunctive form ?

Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your last question is "no" even for 2 variables. Specifically, (a OR b) cannot be represented as an AND of any number of XOR expressions. There are very few different XOR expressions in up to 2 variables: false, true, a, b, !a, !b, (a XOR b), and (a XOR !b). If you AND with any of these: false, true, a, b, !a, !b, (a XOR b), (a XOR !b) you'll set to false one of the 4 possible combinations of (a, b). This leaves only expression true, which is different from (a OR b).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and there is an efficient algorithm for it. You follow normal algebra rules modulo 2. Regarding the previous comment:

```
A|B=A^B^AB
```

This form is called Algebraic normal form 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form